# Error in PageAdapter and Fragment Activity for Tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am making tabs for my dashboard.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffff">

<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/WELCOME"
          android:textSize="40dip"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:layout_marginTop="20dip"/>

   <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/emailTextView"/>

<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Logout_Me"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    android:textColor="#21dbd4"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dip"
    android:background="@null"/>

<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But I constantly get errors in these two java files:
TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.java

```
package com.example.loginandregistration;

IMPORTS

public class TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

// Declare Variables
ActionBar mActionBar;
ViewPager mPager;
Tab tab;

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from dashboard.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

    // Activate Navigation Mode Tabs
    mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Locate ViewPager in activity_main.xml
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    // Activate Fragment Manager
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    // Capture ViewPager page swipes
    ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener ViewPagerListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            // Find the ViewPager Position
            mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    };

    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPagerListener);
    // Locate the adapter class called ViewPagerAdapter.java
    MyPageAdapter viewpageradapter = new MyPageAdapter(fm);
    // Set the View Pager Adapter into ViewPager
    mPager.setAdapter(viewpageradapter);

    // Capture tab button clicks
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

         @Override
         public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
             // Pass the position on tab click to ViewPager
             mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
         }

         @Override
         public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         }

         @Override
         public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         }
     };



    // Create first Tab
    tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1").setTabListener(tabListener);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab);

    // Create second Tab
    tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2").setTabListener(tabListener);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab);

    // Create third Tab
    tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Tab3").setTabListener(tabListener);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab);

}

}
```

(On lines 46:

```
MyPageAdapter viewpageradapter = new MyPageAdapter(fm);
```

With the error:

```
The constructor MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager) is undefined TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.java  /LoginAndRegistration/src/com/example/loginandregistration  line 46 Java Problem
```

But whenever I add a constructor, I get another error, which makes a continuous error loop)

And MyPageAdapter:

```
package com.example.loginandregistration;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

// Declare the number of ViewPager pages
final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;

public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    switch (arg0) {

    // Open FragmentTab1.java
    case 0:
        FragmentTab1 fragmenttab1 = new FragmentTab1();
        return fragmenttab1;

    // Open FragmentTab2.java
    case 1:
        FragmentTab2 fragmenttab2 = new FragmentTab2();
        return fragmenttab2;

    // Open FragmentTab3.java
    case 2:
        FragmentTab3 fragmenttab3 = new FragmentTab3();
        return fragmenttab3;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return PAGE_COUNT;

}

}
```

(Errors on lines:
18

```
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
```

23

```
FragmentTab1 fragmenttab1 = new FragmentTab1();
```

28

```
FragmentTab2 fragmenttab2 = new FragmentTab2();
```

33

```
 FragmentTab3 fragmenttab3 = new FragmentTab3();
```

With line 18, it says the return type is invalid and says to change it to "(Fragment)"
With lines 23,28,33, it says that the FragmentTabs cannot be resolved to a type but when I put the classes that I want as the FragmentTabs (As shown below:

```
        // Open FragmentTab1.java
    case 0:
        CreatePic createpic = new CreatePic();
        return createpic;
```

)
I get errors that say "CreatePic" is undentified and that the return is wrong (when I click the quickfix, it creates a loop of errors)

How can I fix this?

ADDED CREATEPIC.JAVA (Top):

```
package com.example.loginandregistration;


IMPORTS
public class CreatePic extends View {

//drawing path
private Path drawPath;
//drawing and canvas paint
private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
//initial color
private int paintColor = 0xFF660000, paintAlpha = 255;
//canvas
private Canvas drawCanvas;
//canvas bitmap
private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
//brush sizes
private float brushSize, lastBrushSize;
//erase flag
private boolean erase=false;

public CreatePic(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    setupDrawing();
}

//setup drawing
private void setupDrawing(){

    //prepare for drawing and setup paint stroke properties
    brushSize = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.medium_size);
    lastBrushSize = brushSize;
    drawPath = new Path();
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
}

//size assigned to view
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}

//draw the view - will be called after touch event
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
}
```

Comment: Just a simple question, are you using the Android Support Library v4 ? Because there is Fragments and FragmentsV4 but they are not the same :/

Comment: Do you definitely have the imports - import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
in your TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity class?

Comment: And are you sure that the public class MyPageAdapter is either defined WITHIN the TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity class or imported correctly?

Comment: @o0rebelious0o: I didn't have all of those imports so I added them. Here are my imports in my TabsViewPagerFragment:
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

Comment: @o0rebelious0o: And I think so... I have the Variables:
    ActionBar mActionBar;
    ViewPager mPager;
    Tab tab;
and I have the line of code:
'MyPageAdapter viewpageradapter = new MyPageAdapter(fm);'

Comment: @Kyu_: Yes, I am using the Android Support Libary v4...where do you see FragmentsV4 and Fragments?
(Added on: Oh, I see. I changed the import in MyPageAdapter to use Fragment V4 and now the error on line 18 is gone. Thanks for noticing)

Comment: @o0rebelious0o: I also added the import 'import com.example.loginandregistration.MyPageAdapter;' but I still get the constructor error

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have all your imports corrected. You have to create a fragment for your CreatePic. Go to File > New > Class and name it CreatePic.java

```
public class CreatePic extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the view from createpic.xml
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.createpic , container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        setUserVisibleHint(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have already created my CreatePic.java so how would I go about doing this? (I will add the top part of my CreatePic.java into the question)(Note: the createpic.java runs through a createpicmainactivity class so if you need to see the onCreate and things let me know)

Comment: In my MyPageAdapter I am. But I wonder if I am formatting it wrong or not (as shown in the question--the last part before I put the createpic)?

Comment: This is the other error I get:http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=amz80m&s=5#.UkT1xxbnZAg

Comment: Its because your CreatePic is extending View and not Fragment.

Comment: But when I extend Fragment, I have to delete most attributes of my CreatePic. So, is there a way I can extend Fragment without it affecting anything?

Comment: Can you please help me with this step? I'm new to android and mostly have been following tutorials so far so I'm not quite sure on how I would do this and yet keep the CreatePic class working the same. I started a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051869/allow-already-made-class-to-use-fragment-for-tabs) I would greatly apperciate this as I don't have much more time to work on my app. Thanks for you help so far by the way :)

Comment: I'll take a look at your new question.